# Can a late 2013 Mac Pro (cylinder) support dual 5K displays?

Tags: display, mac-pro, displayport

[I know the late 2013 Mac Pro can support the Dell 5K monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202856), using two DisplayPort cables from the Mac to the monitor.

Can the Mac Pro support **two** 5K monitors simultaneously (using four cables total)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - three 5K displays are supported on even the least GPU endowed Mac Pro Late 2013.

While I do not have the luxury of owning this kind of a setup, the following coming directly from Apple should answer this:

[Mac Pro (Late 2013) - Technical Specifications](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP697)

Comment: I'd like to chime in that I'm currently, and regularly, pushing two 4k Dell displays, *and* two 5k HP displays (`Z27q`s), simultaneously. There's occasionally a little jank; and it's not like I'm running high-graphics-requirements video-games while doing so, but it's definitely supported and effective. (=